# creating and modifying .exe file?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scripting, vbscript

How to create an .exe file and how can I modify exsisting .exe file?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE

Answer (score 2):

Typically EXE files are created by something like C# or VB.NET.  You can create EXE files from batch files.  For the most part you can't decompile EXE files back into source code.

Answer (score 1):

Exe extension files are executable BINARY CODE. You are not able to modify them. Technically you could use IDA Pro or something to decompile to assembly, but judging from your question this may prove a little difficult.

I really don't understand how your question relates to your tags... Are you trolling?